# Dynamically map in React depending on the props received

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a component that takes the props. If it's "1", it should use dataOne selector in order to use the right selector with filters. If it's "2" then use dataTwo and so on.

For example:

```
const [dataSet] = useState(route.params.dataSet);

  const dataOne = useSelector(selectDataOne);
  const dataTwo = useSelector(selectDataTwo);
  const dataThree = useSelector(selectDataTwo);
  const dataFour = useSelector(selectDataTwo);
```

The problem is that I want to map through one of these selectors depending on the prop and I want an elegant solution for it as `dataSet[0].map` while dataSet === "dataOne" will not work of course. What would be the alternative? What would be the prefer way to do so? Create a separate component with the switch statement? I want an elegant solution instead of spamming ternary operators like:

```
{dataSet == "1" && dataOne.map etc.}
{dataSet == "2" && dataTwo.map etc.}
```

What would be the best way to take the name from the props and map through it?

EDIT: For now I have this working solution, but not sure if it's the prettiest one:

const Data = (dataSet: string) => {
switch (dataSet) {
case "1":
return dataOne.map((c: any, i: number) => {
const card = c.dataSet === 1 && ;

```
      if (i === dataOne.length - 1) {
        return (
          <View key={i} style={styles.lastMargin}>
            <Card key={i} data={c} isOperating={c.isOperating} />
          </View>
        );
      }

      return card;
    });
  case "2":
    return dataTwo.map((c: any, i: number) => {
      const card = c.dataSet === 2 && <Card key={i} data={c} isOperating={c.isOperating} />;

      if (i === dataTwo.length - 1) {
        return (
          <View key={i} style={styles.lastMargin}>
            <Card key={i} data={c} isOperating={c.isOperating} />
          </View>
        );
      }

      return card;
    });
  case "3":
    return dataThree.map((c: any, i: number) => {
      const card = c.dataSet === 3 && <Card key={i} data={c} isOperating={c.isOperating} />;

      if (i === dataThree.length - 1) {
        return (
          <View key={i} style={styles.lastMargin}>
            <Card key={i} data={c} isOperating={c.isOperating} />
          </View>
        );
      }

      return card;
    });
  case "4":
    return dataFour.map((c: any, i: number) => {
      const card = c.dataSet === 4 && <Card key={i} data={c} isOperating={c.isOperating} />;

      if (i === dataFour.length - 1) {
        return (
          <View key={i} style={styles.lastMargin}>
            <Card key={i} data={c} isOperating={c.isOperating} />
          </View>
        );
      }

      return card;
    });
}
```

};

Comment: what is the type of your prop? is it literally numbers stored as strings or is that just changed for the purpose of this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely shouldn't repeat your render logic. One way to do this could be by mapping each prop to a selector, getting the right one into a variable, and then using that in the render.

```
// map each prop to a selector
const selectorsMap = {
  "1": dataOne,
  "some-value": dataTwo,
  ...
};

// access the correct selector based on the prop
const data = selectorMap[dataSet];


return data.map(...);
```